# map atan value to positive 0-360 degree in java

Tags: java

How to convert the obtained angle(**sLine**) to 0-360 degree in java programming.
I have tried this but not giving the expected result.

```
double sLine = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan((cy - start_point_y) / (cx - start_point_x)));  
sLine = sLine + Math.ceil( -sLine / 360 ) * 360;
```

here (cx,cy) and (start_point_x,start_point_y) are two points.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this:

```
 double angle =  Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(cy - start_point_y,cx - start_point_x));

if(angle < 0){
    angle += 360;
}
//otherwise use angle
```

Comment: THanks man but I solved this issue by checking the quadrant :)